# Can I use a DHT22 sensor with the servo hat installed on my RPi-3?

Tags: servo, dht22, hat

the title pretty much says it all...

My son an I are doing some robotics experimenting with the RPi-2 and RPi-3, we are using the Servo Hat to control several servos on them.

We would like to attach a DHT22 Temp/Humidity sensor to/through the servo hat. 
Can it be done ?

Thanks Dave O.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly.

It depends on the model of servo hat you have bought.

Does it allow you to plug in jumper wires?

If so try my http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_DHTXXD

If not just drive your servo using my [library](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) and use the above linked software.